# ArrayFilter in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, array-filter

Convert the query into node. In which version arrayfilter work in mongoose or how can run these in node app

```
db.getCollection('student').update(
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId('5a377d62d21a3025a3c3aa49')
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "examples.$[i].isDeleted": true,
            "examples.$[i].updatedAt": new Date(),
            "updatedAt": new Date()
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                "i._id": { 
                    $in:[
                        ObjectId("5a377d62d21a3025a3c3aa4d"),
                        ObjectId("5a377d62d21a3025a3c3aa4c")
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        multi: true
    }
)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Answer (score 0):

According to Release **Notes for MongoDB 3.6**
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/

(@ Compatible Drivers) to get access to mongodb 3.6 features it is required to use the node driver 3.x.

It seems that the driver is in RC state *(as of the time being of this answer)*.
https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases

And as such, probably, mongoose is still waiting to start using it.
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/package.json

So you have to wait until these things are arranged or of course you can try to wire things up by your self until the official adaptation is done.

---

-- **Update** --

Now it works fine.